# Heroku doesn't allow temporary downloads. How can I work around this limitation?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am trying to download images from MongoDB every time my app starts so it will work fast and as the images are in the app, but Heroku crashes. How can I solve this?

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
dir = "./public/media/"
    function getAllImages() {
        Image.find({}, function (err, allImages) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                allImages.forEach(file => {
                    fs.writeFile(dir + file.name, file.img.data, function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('Sucessfully saved!');
                    });
                });
            };
        });
```

I currently have 24 images which add up to approximately 10 MB. I will use them as static images in my application. I would like to access them via `example.com/media/foo.jpg`, etc.

Comment: Could you share some code? How many images are?

Comment: Why are you trying to put these files into a directory temporarily? What do you intend to do with them?

Comment: "so it will work fast and as they are in the app"—it will work _faster_ if they're on a CDN. Heroku works just fine with Amazon S3 and countless other services. Why fight it? Assuming they're not part of your application, don't fight this. Host your images off-site.

Comment: If they _are_ part of your application (e.g., hard-coded logos or icons) it's probably still a good idea to host them on S3, but you can also track them in your Git repository and host them statically using whatever static file serving library you want.

Comment: you are making a good point but i never tried it can you make it clearer for me? users posting images in my site too so that is the reason i use db how should i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User uploads can't be stored on Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes made to it will be lost whenever your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). Heroku recommends storing uploaded files on a service like [Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

You can have your users [upload files directly from their browsers to S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node) or you could use the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) to save files from your back-end. A higher-level library like [`multer-s3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3) might be helpful too.

It's not usually a good idea to store files *in* your database, but you can store a *pointer* to files in your database. For example, you might store `https://domain.tld/path/to/some/image.jpg` in your database if that's where the file actually lives.

Answer (score 0):

I just learn that the problem was the folder that i use (./public/media) was empty so heroku (even though it is there in the git system) did not create the folder. Because of this the code `fs.writeFile(dir + file.name, file.img.data, function (err)` didn't work. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: (a) Git doesn't track directories. If the directory is empty it's not going to be in your repository. (b) This might appear to work in the short-term, but as I mentioned in my answer Heroku's ephemeral filesystem will cause the files to periodically disappear. Even though you got this working it's still a better idea to use Amazon S3 or another similar service.